# Error when building program that uses libusb on Raspberry Pi 2 B

Tags: c, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, libusb-1.0, uinput

I am using Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 2 B with a build-from-source libusb (version 1.0.18 if you're curious).  I am trying to build [this](https://github.com/ToadKing/wii-u-gc-adapter) program on the Pi, but it gives the follow error:

```
cc -c -o wii-u-gc-adapter.o wii-u-gc-adapter.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-format -std=c99 -I/usr/local/include/libusb-1.0     -O2
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:44:4: error: ‘BTN_SOUTH’ undeclared here (not in a function)
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:45:4: error: ‘BTN_WEST’ undeclared here (not in a function)
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:46:4: error: ‘BTN_EAST’ undeclared here (not in a function)
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:47:4: error: ‘BTN_NORTH’ undeclared here (not in a function)
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:48:4: error: ‘BTN_DPAD_LEFT’ undeclared here (not in a function)
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:49:4: error: ‘BTN_DPAD_RIGHT’ undeclared here (not in a function)
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:50:4: error: ‘BTN_DPAD_DOWN’ undeclared here (not in a function)
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:51:4: error: ‘BTN_DPAD_UP’ undeclared here (not in a function)
wii-u-gc-adapter.c: In function ‘handle_payload’:
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:367:23: warning: missing initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:367:23: warning: (near initialization for ‘upload.retval’) [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:386:23: warning: missing initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:386:23: warning: (near initialization for ‘erase.retval’) [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
wii-u-gc-adapter.c: In function ‘adapter_thread’:
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:421:14: warning: missing initializer [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
wii-u-gc-adapter.c:421:14: warning: (near initialization for ‘current_time.tv_nsec’) [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'wii-u-gc-adapter.o' failed
make: *** [wii-u-gc-adapter.o] Error 1
```

If you need any other information, I'll provide it.

**Edit**: Also added the top line for the `make` details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed kernel-headers/kernel-devel/linux-headers(exact name depends on used distro) package? Looks like this program require kernel header file with definitions.

If installing this package won't help please copy-paste full make output, there should be errors about missing file there.

Comment: I shall try installing the kernel headers.

Comment: Tried installing the kernel headers for kernel 3.18, but that didn't work.